# How is $sys_root being assigned a value?

Tags: php

I have been learning php for sometime now.  Besides reading books and doing tutorials i also like to sometimes read other programmers' code.  I have come across this:

```
<?php

    // authentication. 
    include_once($sys_root."/inc/authenticate_check.php");
```

I understand the use for `$sys_root`, but what i don't understand is, how `$sys_root` is being assigned a value.

I have checked and made sure that `$sys_root` is not a special var of PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely another file, that defines `$sys_root`, will `include` or `require` this file.

Comment: So you're saying this file itself is being include into another file that has $sys_root already defined.  That would make sense.

Comment: or he's not showing the whole code and there's already an include before

Comment: @Artefacto: I made the assumption that, since he started with `<?php`, he was trying to signal that the line was at the top of the file... but maybe not!

Comment: and if its as Matchu said, that's poor programming (global vars, ewww) .. it should be a Constant, most likely.